# Progress bar background color is not showing in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello everyone here i am trying to show progress bar for my website but i ma facing problem of not display `background-color` on scroll, please help on this also find the code at below starting from `html`, `css` and `jquery` ...

**HTML Code**

`<div class="progress-bar-container"><div id="progressbar" value="0"></div></div>`

**CSS Code**

```
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #ced4da;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 48px;
    z-index: 440;
}
.progress-bar-container #progressbar {
    background-color: #4688f1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
}
```

**jQuery Code**

```
      $(window).scroll(function () {
          var s = $(document).scrollTop(),
              d = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
          $("#progressbar").attr('max', d);
          $("#progressbar").attr('value', s);
       });
   });
```

Here please guide how i can display backgroud-color on scroll. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: `<div>` element does not have a `value` property. What is the expected result of setting `"value"` and `"max"` attributes at a `<div>` element?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code, HTML width attribute does not support `div` element. Also, the value attribute is not supported by `div` either. For creating the progress bar you could use CSS. Instead of updating  `$("#progressbar").attr('value', s);` value just update the width of the element `$("#progressbar").width(s);`

Here is the complete working example -

```js
  $(window).scroll(function () {
          var s = $(document).scrollTop(),
              d = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
          $("#progressbar").width(s);
   });
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
.progress-bar-container{
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #ced4da;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 48px;
    z-index: 440;
}
.progress-bar-container #progressbar {
    background-color: #4688f1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="progress-bar-container"><div id="progressbar"></div></div>
<div style="height: 120vh"></div>
 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate the procentage and set it as width for `progressbar``
have a look.

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var  d = $(document).height() - $(window).height(),
       s = $(document).scrollTop(); 
  var  width= (s / d) * 100 // in Procent
  $("#progressbar").attr('max', d);
  $("#progressbar").attr('value',s).css("width",width +"%");
});
```

```css
body{
height: 1000px;
}

.progress-bar-container{ 
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #ced4da;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 48px;
    z-index: 440;
}
.progress-bar-container #progressbar {
    background-color: #4688f1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar-container">
<div id="progressbar" value="0"></div>
</div>
```